# Footer won't stay at the bottom of my website in Firefox only

Tags: html, firefox, cross-browser, footer

I have a website with a footer, which shows fine in Chrome and Safari.

When it is viewed in Mozilla Firefox however, the footer is not at the bottom of the page, it is all over the page, starting from under the header.

Is it something to do with using the  and  tags in Firefox? Or something else.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        Stuff.....
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            Stuff....
        </header>

        <div id="main_container">
            <div id="content_container">
                Text (h1, h2 and p tags)
        </div>

        <div id="networking_container">
            <div id="twitter">
                Twitter Feed...
            </div>

            <div class="fb-like" id="facebook" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/EtempaSolutions" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="225" data-show-faces="false">
            </div>

            <g:plusone size="medium" annotation="inline" width="215"></g:plusone>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <table id="favourite_links_table" cellpadding="4">
                Stuff...
            </table>

            <div id="credits">
                <p id='main_credit'>This website has been designed and hosted by <a href='http://www.etempa.co.uk'>Etempa Solutions</a></p>

                <p id='sub_credit'>Web Design, Including Coding and Images © Copyright to Pippa Rose Smith 2012. All Rights Reserved</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

The css bits are:

```
html 
{ 
    padding: 30px 10px; 

    line-height: 1.4; 

    background-color: #CCC;

    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; 

    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
}

html, input 
{   
    font-family: Candara, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
}

body 
{ 
    width: 860px; 

    padding: 20px 30px 20px;

    border: 1px solid #b3b3b3; 

    border-radius: 4px; 

    margin: 0 auto; 

    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px #a7a7a7, inset 0 1px 0 #fff; 

    background: #fcfcfc; 
}

footer
{
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#main_container
{
    clear: both;

    padding-top: 15px;
}

#favourite_links_table
{
    text-align: center;

    width: 850px;
} 

#credits
{
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#main_credit
{
    color: #9933FF;

    font-size: 13px;

    text-align: center;
}

#sub_credit
{
    color: #9933FF;

    font-size: 12px;

    text-align: center;
}

#content_container
{
    float: left;

    width: 70%;
}

#networking_container
{
    float: right;

    width: 25%;
}

#twitter
{
    padding-top: 30px;

    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#facebook
{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: you missed `<html>` on top and please provide your css as well.

Comment: Sorry, html tag added as is css

Comment: It looks the same to me in Chrome and Firefox http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UGg6d/

Comment: Thanks, seems the problem is somewhere in the main container... I've added the extra code. I didn't think it was relevant code but seemes it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer

I've added clear: both to my footer so the css is now

```
footer
{
    margin-top: 30px;

    clear: both;
}
```